# SaltStack: How to target specific minions

Tags: salt-stack

Is it possible to target a specific set of minions when applying a state? Instead of doing:

```
salt '*' state.sls mystate.sls
```

I want to do:

```
salt '[key1,key2,...]' state.sls mystate.sls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, just use -L

`salt -L 'key1,key2,key3,...' state.sls mystate.sls`

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/globbing.html#lists